# Pandas replace value in column with key in dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to replace each value of a column in my pandas df with dict key if the value == the value of the dictionary:

Example `dic`: `{'The Name of the Rose': '9780544176560'}`

Example `df`:

```
ISBN, link
9780544176560, https://link
```

Code:

```
df['ISBN'] = df['ISBN'].astype(str)
for k,v in dic.items():
    for x in df['ISBN']:
        x = str(x)
        if x == v:
            print(True)
            x = k
```

It prints True every time, and if I print x I get the correct titles, but then when I print the df it returns numbers like nothing changed. I also tried `replace` but nothing changed

Comment: I changed the names of the dataframe to `df` and the dictionary to `dic` to match wide usage ;) Also avoid using `dict` as this is a python builtin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [`map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html), but you're building your dictionary the wrong way.

As [ISBN are unique](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Standard_Book_Number), they can be used as key. A book title could not be unique though:

```
dic = {'The Name of the Rose': '9780544176560'}
df = pd.DataFrame({'ISBN': [9780544176560],
                   'link': ['https://link']})

# invert the dictionary if needed
# but the best it to build it directly with ISBN as key
dic = {isbn:title for title,isbn in dic.items()}
# {'9780544176560': 'The Name of the Rose'}

# map the Title from the ISBN
df['Title'] = df['ISBN'].astype(str).map(dic)
```

output:

```
            ISBN          link                 Title
0  9780544176560  https://link  The Name of the Rose
```

Comment: sorry where does df come from?

Comment: This is your dataframe. I see you used `d2`. The convention is to use `d` for dictionaries and `df` for dataframes. I'm editing your question for clarity